# NameError in Admin::ResidentsController#destroy Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activeadmin, activemodel

I am getting name error when I am deleting a resident model object using *active admin*

I have resident model :

```
class Resident < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :leaves,dependent: :delete_all
end
```

And second one is leave model:

```
class Leave < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resident
end
```

Giving me following ***error***:

[image: error that I am getting while deleting resident]

Also rails misinterpreted ***leave*** name and changed it to ***leafe***.. so I renamed Or refactored files :
decorators/leafe_decorator.rb **to** decorators/leave_decorator.rb

*similarly in decorator tests.*

Now I again searched thru my whole code for **Leafe** Keyword but it is not there. And still getting that ***error*** . What should I do ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the integrated pluralization rules of Rails yield a wrong singular for the word "leaves" (which should be "leaf" anyway)

You could just change your models to match the expected word "leafe" or you can teach Rails the correct singular form.

To do that simply add this to an initializer:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'leave', 'leaves'
end
```

There should already be a file named `inflections.rb` in your initializers directory, which documents various other Rails inflection features.

That way your original code should work, without renaming any files or models.

Answer (score 0):

Long shot, but this may be linked with Rails trying to be "smart" about pluralizing model names (like being able to pluralize 'Person' as 'People').

In this situation, I think Rails will expect the model to be Leaf:

```
class Leaf < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resident
end
```

and the association (and table name) to be `leaves`:

```
class Resident < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :leaves, dependent: :delete_all
end
```

Comment: but the key word is LEAFE an extra 'E'

Comment: in `rails console`, `"person".pluralize` => `"people"` and `"leave".pluralize` => `"leaves"`. Also, `:delete_all` should it be `:destroy` ?

Comment: then I should have to rename back all the files that i changed from leafe to leave also ?